# How to serve dynamically changing photo to client via Spring MVC?

Tags: java, image, spring-mvc, web

I wrote an MVC application and I wanted to create an option of editing the photo. I serve image as div which background is the image and div has click listener that post suitable requests to application.
Then on the application side works another program that edits photo as client asked and saves it and override a old one. The problem is that until I redeploy an application it serves an old file even though it has changed. I think the problem is because I serve photos from resources folder and it’s cold “static resources” so I should not change it. Another think is that IntelliJ is not refreshing the photo. Do you have any idea what I do wrong or know how should I serve that photos in better way?

Comment: "I think the problem is because I serve photos from resources folder and it’s cold “static resources” so I should not change it." You probably are right! Try setting cachePeriod to `0`

Answer (score 0):

So as Prashant mentioned in comment all I had to do was setCachePeriod to 0.

**EDIT:**
Following are two ways of doing it:

1. Either set in the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.resources.cache-period = 0
```

2. Or, add in the ResourceHandler:

```
   @Component
   public class WebConfigurations extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
       @Override
       public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registy.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                 .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                 .setCachePeriod(0);
       }
   }
```